# Spring Rest API LocalDate deserialize

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

**I am not using spring boot!**

LocalDate Deserializer

```
public class LocalDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDate> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected LocalDateDeserializer() {
        super(LocalDate.class);
    }


    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println(jp.readValueAs(String.class));
        LocalDate lDate;
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            lDate = LocalDate.parse(jp.readValueAs(String.class), dateTimeFormatter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            lDate = LocalDate.now();
        }
        return lDate;
    }

}
```

User Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String surname;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    LocalDate dob;
    Integer salary;
    String gender;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am calling the post request in here

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(savedUser);
}
```

Error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.FIELD_NAME`)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 3]
```

I am trying to add user to my postgres database using spring web mvc post request but I cannot parse string to localdate class.

Comment: Which `String`? Can you show it?

Comment: POST http://localhost:8080/SpringTrial/api/user/add HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Wick",
  "dob": "1999-01-06",
  "salary": 1000,
  "gender": "WOMAN"
}
this is my request

Comment: Can you please share the POST request body and also the complete stack trace? Thanks

Comment: I just share the POST request body above and there is no stack trace because i am using try catch and print the error. Even if i delete try catch there is no stack trace appears in the console. Just my response returns this https://ibb.co/7CQzJW4